# Power BI show/hide slicer based on another slicer value selection

Tags: hide, show-hide, show, transparent, slicers

Following the [article](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/show-or-hide-a-power-bi-visual-based-on-selection/), I was able to show/hide line charts through applying card measure over line/bar charts visual. It is also required for the project to show/hide other slicers based on primary slicer value. [please see attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JIuu.jpg)

The interaction with slicer's Dropdown icon is not possible once applying card measure over the secondary slicers. Is there any way through DAX or other workaround to send the transparent card back to original visual (slicer in this case) for interaction? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update if you face similar issue, this issue has been resolved through using buttons (instead of slicer) for the Interval values. Then used bookmarks and selection pane to show/hide other slicers/visuals. I found this way much easier and interactive. Thanks.